# Using bash in combination with psql, passing variable between them

Tags: bash, scripts, postgresql

I'm writing a bash script where I use psql (Postgresql).

```
DATABASE='scifi'

sudo -u postgres psql
count=SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database WHERE lower(datname)=lower($DATABASE)
```

I want to delete the database if exist and recreated with the same name and allocated to an user.

Also other operations related to psql.

My issue is that once I enter psql I cannot pass bash commands and retrieve info. I kind of understand why(because I'm moving from bash to psql) but I have to find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass single commands as strings using `-c`, or pass more complex command sequences via standard input for example using a here document:

```
sudo -u postgres psql << EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database 
  WHERE lower(datname)=lower($DATABASE)
)
EOF
```

You may need to quote or escape shell-special characters such as `*` that you do not want to be expanded.

See [PostgreSQL 9.4.19 Documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/app-psql.html)

---

To capture the result, use the shell's `$(...)` *command substitution* syntax:

```
count=$(sudo -u postgres psql << EOF
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
  SELECT datname FROM pg_catalog.pg_database 
  WHERE lower(datname)=lower($DATABASE)
)
EOF
)
```

Comment: how do I get the result back in bash ?

Comment: @user3541631 please see updated answer